# Is Hadoop installation mandatory when using Apache Mahout

Tags: mahout

Does Apache mahout work without Hadoop , If not so which parts specifically of mahout are dependent on Hadoop . I am trying Mahout clustering implementations .

Thanks .
Shahid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Mahout [FAQ](https://mahout.apache.org/general/faq.html), Hadoop is not required for all of the algorithms implemented in Mahout, including:

- User-based collaborative filtering
- Item-based collaborative filtering
- Matrix factorization with alternating least squares
- Matrix factorization with alternating least squares on implicit feedback
- Weighted matrix factorization
- Logistic regression
- Hidden Markov models
- Canopy clustering
- k-means clustering
- Fuzzy k-means
- Streaming k-means
- Singular value decomposition
- Lanczos algo